# Extracting multiple JSON files into one dataframe

Tags: r, json

I am trying to merge multiple json files into one database and despite trying all the approaches found on SO, it fails.

The files provide sensor data. The stages I've completed are:

```
1. Unzip the files - produces json files saved as '.txt' files
2. Remove the old zip files
3. Parse the '.txt' files to remove some bugs in the content - random 3 
letter + comma combos at the start of some lines, e.g. 'prm,{...'
```

I've got code which will turn them into data frames individually:

```
stream <- stream_in(file("1.txt"))
flat <- flatten(stream)
df_it <- as.data.frame(flat)
```

But when I put it into a function:

```
df_loop <- function(x) {
  stream <- stream_in(x)
  flat <- flatten(stream)
  df_it <- as.data.frame(flat)
  df_it
}
```

And then try to run through it:

```
df_all <- sapply(file.list, df_loop)
```

I get:

```
Error: Argument 'con' must be a connection.
```

Then I've tried to merge the json files with rbind.fill and merge to no avail.

Not really sure where I'm going so terribly wrong so would appreciate any help.

Comment: is `file.list` a list of file paths? In that case you need to do `stream <- stream_in(file(x))` in your function

Comment: That worked a treat but would you help me understand why?

Comment: added ans pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a small change in your function. Change to -

```
stream <- stream_in(file(x))
```

**Explanation**

Start with analyzing your original implementation -

```
stream <- stream_in(file("1.txt"))
```

The `1.txt` here is the file path which is getting passed as an input parameter to `file()` function. A quick `?file` will tell you that it is a

> Function to create, open and close connections, i.e., “generalized
>   files”, such as possibly compressed files, URLs, pipes, etc.

Now if you do a `?stream_in()` you will find that it is a

> function that implements line-by-line processing of JSON data over a
>   connection, such as a socket, url, file or pipe

Keyword here being `socket, url, file or pipe`.

Your `file.list` is just a list of file paths, character/strings to be specific. But in order for `stream_in()` to work, you need to pass in a `file` object, which is the output of `file()` function which takes in the file path as a string input.

Chaining that together, you needed to do `stream_in(file("/path/to/file.txt"))`.

Once you do that, your `sapply` takes   iterates each path, creates the file object and passes it as input to `stream_in()`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated! Will get back to work trying to merge them with rbind.fill or something similar.

Comment: I've followed your advice but now merging into one dataframe seems to crash. What do you think I'm missing to stream_in the files, flatten them and append them to one large data frame?